# Using AJAX to access the content of a view

Tags: views, ajax, javascript

I have a simple view with one exposed filter that displays a table view of contents.(for example nodes are some addresses with the exposed filter of the city). And I made a map for cities;I want that whenever user clicks on a city in the map, the selected city become exposed filter of view and view become refreshed without refreshing the whole page.is it possible?
I thought that I can use something like:

```
$.get(
'/myviewpage',
{myfield=14},
function(data){  $('#SomeOtherDiv').html(data) }
);
```

I tried that but I got unauthorized error. if it's correct; how can I make a page view-able for everyone?
thanks

Comment: Related: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/106747/how-to-load-and-display-a-view-with-ajax-in-drupal-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would do it (and it works):

Instead of directly calling the page with JQuery $.get, you should use the Drupal ajax framework and call a custom path you created with hook_menu with a callback function which calls the view and return it using ajax_deliver. Then you create your own js function for the response.

There is some nice documentatione/example about this, particularly [this one](http://www.angrydonuts.com/drupal-7-advanced-ajax-tips-and-tricks).

Comment: An example of how adding code would be useful... The site no longer exists....

Answer (score 3):

First, enable Ajax on the view. On window load, bind the click event to a custom function, let's call it `getInfo(arg)` and pass the arguments you need (*nid*, *tid*, or whatever you need)

Then, on `getInfo()` add the following code.

```
function getInfo(args) {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/views/ajax',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
      view_name: 'your_view_name',
      view_display_id: 'block_1', //your display id
      view_args: args,
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
      if (response[1] !== undefined) {
        var viewHtml = response[1].data;
        $('#myDiv').html(viewHtml);
        Drupal.attachBehaviors(); //check if you need this.
      }
    }
  });
}
```

You pass the arguments in the data array, and you get the #myDiv replaced with the view content.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use hook_menu. Exposed filter of view send request to /views/ajax, you can add param for this request 
view_name=[view_name]&view_display_id=[view_display_id],
so you only get the content that you want.
If you want to use JSON, install views_datasource